# changing numeric data variable into date format in R to merge two datasets

Tags: r, date, numeric, merging-data

I am trying to merge two datasets where `date` and an `id` variable are the two common identifiers.

In one dataset the `date` variable is of `character` type and looked like this: `'31jan2013'`. We thus used the `as.Date` function to change it into date format (`as.Date(dataset1$date, format = "%d%b%Y")` creating a new date column that shows the date like this: `'2013-01-31'`.

The issue comes in when we want to change the other date variable from our second dataset. In `dataset2` the `date` variable is of `numeric` nature and looks like this: `'20130131'`. We again tried to use the `as.Date` function (`as.Date.numeric(dataset2$date["datadate"], "%Y%m%d")` however we get this error:

```
**Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How about:  `as.Date(as.character(...), format="%Y%m%d")`.

Comment: Btw, if `as.Date(x)` is called with `x` of class `character`, or directly via `as.Date.character(x)`, the second parameter should be `format`. However, if `as.Date(x)` is called with `x` of class `numeric`, or directly via `as.Date.numeric(x)`, the second parameter is `origin`. Because of this behaviour, you should convert your parameter into class `character`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be using the lubridate package.

For example

```
lubridate::ymd('20130131')
lubridate::ymd(20130131)
lubridate::ymd(dataset2$date)
```

Comment: great information on how to work with dates in R can be found here: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score 0):

The date format can be specified with the `format` parameter.

```
as.Date('20130131', format = "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2013-01-31"
```

If the data is numeric

```
as.Date(as.character(20130131), format = "%Y%m%d")
[1] "2013-01-31"
```

Comment: This would not work though if the data is numeric (as stated in the question). `as.Date(as.character(20130131) format = "%Y%m%d")`, would work, but is a bit ugly in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. I've added this to my answer.